# Which syscalls are blocking in linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, system-calls

I tried to find the `API` of linux and found partial list in [syscalls.h](http://elixir.free-electrons.com/linux/v3.14/source/include/linux/syscalls.h). How can I identify whether an application of interest uses blocking ones (I plan collect information using `strace`)?

Comment: I'm afraid, the question is not quite clear. Do you plan to ground your assessments of blocking/non-blocking behaviour based on some API reference? I see, you say, that in the end you plan to use `strace` to collect information. But why are you trying to look up `syscalls.h`, etc? Say, my application can use `recv()` syscall both in blocking and non-blocking modes (`MSG_DONTWAIT` flag). How the knowledge of `recv()` API will help to understand what mode does a particular application use?

Comment: @BronislavElizavetin That's a valuable input. Those who program in high level languages might not be aware of that but still suffer consequences (for example during garbage collection).

Comment: Probably, they do. But what else shall we discuss with respect to your question?

Comment: man <systemcallname> will solve your problem.